# Where is the subject in "[...] weaker than would otherwise have been the case"?

Tags: inversion, comparative-constructions, parsing, supplementation

Where is the subject in the following dependent clause?

> [...] Germany adopted a much weaker currency **than would otherwise have been the case** [...] (taken from [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-18868704))

Is *"the case"* the subject? I don't think so. Imagine I re-write the sentence as:

> Germany adopted a much weaker currency **than would otherwise have been possible**

My inability to tell what is the subject in those sentences makes me feel there is something wrong?

If I try to find the subject by asking: *"what would it otherwise have been the case?"*, I would answer the subject is "**that** Germany adopted a much **stronger** currency".

The meaning is clear but the grammar feels wrong.

Could anyone explain the grammar involved in this sentence?

---

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**

This [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=than+it+would+otherwise+have+been%2C+than+would+otherwise+have+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthan%20would%20otherwise%20have%20been%3B%2Cc0) shows that *"than it would otherwise have been"* is never used.

Is it wrong to write the following? If so, why?

> <strike>Germany adopted a much weaker currency than **it** would otherwise have been the case</strike>

Comment: Some words are intentionally omitted, say for the sake of style. The sentence can be rewritten as this - "Germany adopted a much weaker currency than it would otherwise have been the case". This is what I think. I have opened that link and I didn't understand the paragraph. Without that understanding I think the subject of this sentence is "it".

Comment: Inserting *it* would render the sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: Can you please explain, because I can't figure it out? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry the sentence with "than it" is correct. Compare: I bought a house bigger than I needed. Same construction, with subject following than.

Comment: I also don't see a big problem with "than it would otherwise been the case". The word "it" seems superfluous, an obvious target for elision, but it's not jarring my ear.

Comment: Seems like this should go to EL&U.

Comment: Hi @CoolHandLouis Do you mean this question should be asked again on EL&U? or you simply mean that this question would have been of interest to EL&U. Do I need to do anything?

Comment: Nico, I think the answers *turned out* to be more complex than perhaps expected - more complex than typical for ell.se.  It was just a suggestion.  I don't know if moderators can move questions from ell.se to EL&U.se, or even if it would be warranted in this case.  Perhaps @J.R. or any other more advanced user can give guidance.  I certainly don't want to overstep my bounds or **be more of a trouble-maker than I expressly attempt to be.**  Probably if you're happy with it, it could just be left alone here. ;)

Comment: Your Ngram query is invalid. If you run the query, you'll note that it says: *"than it would otherwise have been" has length greater than five. Omitting ngram from results.* It's not showing that phrase because it's not even considering it. You can only use ngram's that contain five or fewer words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ‘A Student’s Introduction to English Grammar’, Huddleston and Pullum write that there are three major subclasses of dependent clause.  One of these subclasses is the **comparative clause**.  Here’s their example:

> More people came than **had been invited**.

They further note that this clause “has no overt subject at all.”  Your sentence seems to be a similar case.  We might think the clause is based on “people had been invited”, as for your sentence “it would otherwise have been the case.”  But “people” and “it” cannot appear.

Again according to Huddleston and Pullum, one of the distinguishing features of this type of clause is that “they are obligatorily **reduced** in certain ways relative to the structure of main clauses.” (p. 201)  It seems that subjects, predicative complements or degree modifiers just have to be left out, and the sentence in question is one case of this.

**Edit:**  If we take the underlying form as “the case would otherwise have been [that Germany adopted a stronger currency]”, then this would be SV inversion in the comparative clause as @Nico suggests.  However, “it was the case that X” seems more natural to me than “the case was that X”.  Therefore I would still prefer to treat this as omission of the dummy subject “it” rather than inversion.

Comment: In "more people came than had been invited", we can easily regard the situation as a case of elision of the "people" subject: "more people came than [[how many] people] had been invited".

Comment: I've compared the [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+the+case%2Cthe+case+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20the%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20case%20was%3B%2Cc0) of "was the case" and "the case was" and supports that "it was the case" sounds more natural.

Answer (score 5):

## To Complement @user2619 's answer

I would like to complement @user2619 's answer with another piece of information that I managed to find in the [Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8v_SS6_9S34C&dq=longman+written+spoken+grammar).

In Table 12.3 "Special types of inversion in dependent clauses", I find a case that I think it is relevant to answer my question:

**comparative clauses with *"as"* an *"than"***

> Independent agencies are in better position to offer personal service **than are those** tied to big chains.

This table explains that in this type of sentences the operator (*"are"* in the case above) follows the subordinator (in this case "as"). Using this interpretation I can say that:

- the main clause is *"Independent agencies are in better position to offer personal service"*.
- the dependent clause is *"**than are** those tied to big chains"*.
- the dependent clause shows a subject-verb inversion, and without the inversion the clause would be *"**than** those tied to big chains **are**"*.

---

## And the full answer to my original question

Combining this information with the information in @user2619 's answer, I'm now able to interpret both sentences:

> 1. Germany adopted a much weaker currency than would otherwise have been the case
> 2. Germany adopted a much weaker currency than would otherwise have been possible

The first sentence can be interpreted as an example of the **subject-verb inversion** described in [Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8v_SS6_9S34C&dq=longman+written+spoken+grammar).

And the second sentence can be interpreted as an example of the **obligatory ellipsis** described in ["A Student’s Introduction to English Grammar"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C) by Huddleston and Pullum.

Comment: Interesting! Another way to paraphrase this: “than it otherwise would have/it would otherwise have done." Again some reduction/ellipsis going on.

Answer (score 2):

The subject is "it" which is not mentioned before would.

... than it would otherwise have been the case

Comment: Should I write "it"? or removing "it" is a common use with "than"?

Comment: it is often omitted.. as you can see from the BBC news...

Comment: Downvote or not, this is the correct answer to the question of what is the subject in the relative clause. There is an understood subject here, like "it" which is elided.