# You're taller than (is/are) described

Tags: comparative-constructions

> You're taller than described.

I think 'be' is omitted between 'than' and 'described', right?

If so, what's the correct form of 'be'?

> a. You're taller than **are** described.
>
> b. You're taller than **is** described.

And why?

Comment: Why do you think that the option with **are** could possibly be used?

Comment: @CowperKettle I didn't say it could possibly or should be **are**. Why do YOU think that the option with **are** could NOT possibly be used?

Comment: It's you who are studying the language, not me, so I wanted to understand your thinking and see whether you expended any effort at investigating the issue.

Comment: @CowperKettle If the omitted subject is 'you' I don't see why 'are' is not possible. BTW, even grammarians "are studying the language".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment under the question, you said:

> If the omitted subject is 'you' I don't see why 'are' is not possible.

The verb for of **to be** would be **are** if it followed the subject **you**. Except that it doesn't. In this case, the verb *described* (barring further context that isn't known from the sentence alone) doesn't have an explicit subject.

We can't assign the act of description to anybody (singular or plural) because the sentence doesn't say *who* is describing the thing, either directly or indirectly. Because there is no explicit subject, the subject becomes the dummy subject **it**. In other words:

> **It is** described that you are a certain height.

---

While the *to be* has been omitted from the original sentence, so has this subject. In other words:

> You're taller than described.
>   → You're taller than **is** described.
>   → You're taller than **it is** described.

---

There is a way in which you could use **you are**, but it would require a longer form of sentence:

> You're taller than **you are described** (as being / to be).

But we can't omit the second *you* without it sounding unnatural—because the assumption (from normal speech) is that the shorter version is a short form of the dummy subject form of sentence. (And *it are* would be wrong.)

---

It's also possible to remove the dummy it altogether by changing the verb to a noun:

> You're taller than **your description**.

---

However, if we knew from context that it was *you* who had provided the description, then the sentence would not use the dummy it—but it would still be different than you suggest.

It would be something like one of the following:

> You're taller than **you** described.
>   You're taller than **you had** described.
>   You're taller than **you describe**.
>   You're taller than **you have been describing**.

In all of these cases, the repetition of *you* is necessary in order to distinguish it from the dummy subject version.

Comment: Are you suggesting _You're taller than it is described_ is possible English?? Regarding my comment about the omitted subject possibly being 'you', I meant that 'you' could be the subject of the passive construction, because 'described' in the original sentence has to be the past participle form of the verb. For example, I was thinking something alone the lines of _You're taller than you are described to be._

Comment: Yes. *You're taller than it is described* is fine. Normally it's shortened, but the longer version is what it actually stands for. (I've also updated my answer to account for what you had been thinking.)

Comment: But don't you need the that-clause at the end, if you're to add 'it' there? For example, shouldn't it be something like _You're taller than it is described that you are_?

Comment: @listeneva No, it's not needed. Like many examples of ellipsis, the final part is optional.

Comment: Is this different from _He worries more than (it) is necessary_? Here, I think 'it' is also a dummy subject, and a grammar book (Practical English Usage) says you have to omit it.

Comment: @listeneva It's the same principle of a dummy subject. And you certainly do not *have* to omit it. It's just that it often is omitted because it reads more smoothly without it—and we assume its presence to be there anyway. (An even longer version of that sentence would be: *He worries more than it is necessary for him to worry.*)

Comment: So are you saying the grammar book is wrong? I'm really confused, because I've managed to find a similar question here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19969/where-is-the-subject-in-weaker-than-would-otherwise-have-been-the-case There, they cite another grammar book called 'A Student's Introduction to English Grammar' (I don't have this one), which also claims that the omission of the dummy subject "it" is obligatory. And the consensus of the answers there seems to be in line with the book.

Comment: @listeneva The examples in the other question are different, grammatically, and it would not be grammatical for them to use **it**. (Although if altered slightly, those examples with **it** are possible.) The grammar here is very specific. It's not possible to address this in these comments, or even within the scope of this question. I suggest asking a separate question on the use of **it** specifically.